# NetworkManager-wait-online.service Failed

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu (actually Lubuntu) on a Windows host.  I was upgrading from version 16 to 17.10 when I got a screen saying something about systemctl having a new version and do I want to keep the old version, view the difference, or go with the new version.  I accidently continued I believe with the old version and now my VM won't boot properly.

I get the following services fail at startup:

gpu-manager.service
lightdm.service
NetworkManager-wait-online.service
plymouth-start.service

If I try to `ping 8.8.8.8`, I get "Network is Unreachable"

```
$route -n
```

doesn't return any entries.

```
$sudo ip route add default My.Router.IP.Address
```

Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.

The output of ifconfig:[image]